# Using Dotfuscator with Fody/Costura

Tags: c#, obfuscation, dotfuscator, fody

I use **Fody/Costura** to embed my Class Library inside Console Application resources, I want to obfuscate my Application and Class Library using **Dotfuscator**.

Since, **Dotfuscator CE** runs after build - Class Library already inside Application resources and don't obfuscating.

How I can obfuscate both? Or obfuscate before resource embedding?